# Blazor: How to get the hosted service instance?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I added a background service that periodically does something, like the official sample.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>(); <-- here
    services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
}
```

The [TimedHostedService](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/b7bcde6905be1828b21d70fbf695f576695a43ec/aspnetcore/fundamentals/host/hosted-services/samples/3.x/BackgroundTasksSample/Services/TimedHostedService.cs) has `StartAsync` and `StopAsync`. Ultimately, I want to call these in the web browser.

In the `FetchData.razor` file in the default scaffolding, I tried to refer that service directly, but that did not work. So, I added `Start` and `Stop` method to the `WeatherForecastService` and called them on the click event.

```
<button @onclick="()=> { ForecastService.Stop(); }">Stop</button>
```

Now, the problem is, that I don't know how to get the running instance of `TimedHostedService` in the `Stop` method of `WeatherForecastService`.

```
public class WeatherForecastService
{
....
    public void Stop()
    {
        //how to get TimedHostedService instance?
    }
....
}
```

I have tried using dependency injection to  get the service provider, but `GetService` returned null.

```
IServiceProvider sp;
public WeatherForecastService(IServiceProvider sp)
{
    this.sp = sp;
}

public void Stop()
{
    var ts = sp.GetService(typeof(TimedHostedService)) as TimedHostedService;
    ts.StopAsync(new CancellationToken());
}
```

Comment: Hosted Service start and stops automatically by web framework, when application starts or stops.If you want to have control of background tasks, probably you can start another worker/thread in hosted service, which you will be able to stop manually.

Comment: @Fabio It did automatically start, but I want to stop and start again as necessary. If I look into the class of `TimedHostedService`, the start/stop methods do not interact with the framework; all they do is starting/stopping the internal timer, so I thought there would be no harm to call the start/stop method myself.

Comment: Then do not register it as Hosted Service but just as a singleton. Then in controller you can pass it as constructor parameter and call `Start` or `Stop` from controller action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I question the wisdom of manipulating the service from the GUI but if you're sure you want this then it's about how to register that service.

In startup:

```
services.AddSingleton<TimedHostedService>();
services.AddHostedService(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<TimedHostedService>());
```

and then you can

```
@inject TimedHostedService TimedService
```

Comment: If this is a bad way, what kind of way would you suggest? I don't think what I am trying to do is a bizarre one. For example, if you want to (1)check a website at each minute continuously, but also (2)want to pause/resume that if there is such a need. I thought I create a web application and put (1) in a background service (IHosteService), put the web application on an always-on server, and then use the the Blazor web page to do (2) in a web browser on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Share a singleton service between your UI and your Hosted service.  Manipulate the values in the UI and consume the values in the Hosted service.  Set up a timer in the Hosted Service.

Whenever I've done this, I set a property in the singleton like "IsStop".  Then I use the singleton as a data transport.  On the view, set the singleton.IsStop value to true.  The next time the HostedService cycles I check the singleton.IsStop where I kill the timer.  I typically include a RunFrequency and IsPause property also to define how often the timer should run and if I want to keep the timer in place but pause the logic execution.